# actual implementation is getting triggered when using MockRestServiceServer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am using resttemplate to call other rest services. And writing junit for the same. While running it is returning null that says it is not using mock implementation

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class OrganizationEmployeeServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private OrganizationEmployeeServiceImpl organizationEmployeeService;

    private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        restTemplate = null;
        organizationEmployeeService = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testMockCreation() {
        assertNotNull(restTemplate);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetEmployeesByOrganizationId() throws JsonProcessingException {
        List<Employee> testEmployees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        Employee employee1 = new Employee();
        employee1.setEmployeeId(11);
        employee1.setName("malav1");
        employee1.setCity("bangalore1");
        employee1.setOrganizationId(29);
        testEmployees.add(employee1);

        Employee employee2 = new Employee();
        employee1.setEmployeeId(12);
        employee1.setName("malav2");
        employee1.setCity("bangalore2");
        employee1.setOrganizationId(29);
        testEmployees.add(employee2);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String result = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(testEmployees);

        mockServer.expect(requestTo("http://localhost:8080/springjpacontroller/employees/29")).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
                .andRespond(withSuccess(result, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        List<Employee> resultEmployees = organizationEmployeeService.getEmployeesByOrganizationId(29);
        assertNotNull(resultEmployees);
        mockServer.verify();
    }
}
```

service class method:

```
@Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public void setRestTemplate(RestTemplate restTemplate){
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Employee> getEmployeesByOrganizationId(int organizationId) {
        Employee[] employees = restTemplate.getForObject(
                "http://localhost:8080/"+ EMPLOYEE_SERVICE_ENDPOINT + organizationId, Employee[].class);
        return Arrays.asList(employees);
    }
```

here while running the junit it giving assertinerror because this employeesresult is null.

Comment: If you don't specify what to return, a mock will return null.  when(restservice.employeemthod(resource)).thenReturn(valueToReturn);

Comment: that is not required here i think. this method internally uses resttemplate.getforobject,,so do we need that

Comment: You're using a mock RestTemplate. So it won't do anything you don't tell it o do using the Mockito API. If you want the RestTemplate to call your mock server, it must be a real RestTemplate, not a mock one.

Comment: You could also look into using TestRestTemplate https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/web/client/TestRestTemplate.html

Comment: @JBNizet hey when i am just doing new RestTemplate() instead of mocking it it is working fine, but i dont understand why so ? Could you please explain me why it works that way ? Thanks